# DEC / ASCII codes for ALL mac keys

Tags: mac, code

I have a few questions:

1: Which key codes are used in Terminal? DEC right?

2: How do I find the values of all my keys? Any program I have found to do it for you won't work on function keys which is what I want. Eventually, I want to be able to change my key lighting from Terminal using key press commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick research turned up a tool called [Except](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) which can be used to automate tasks in the terminal (like sending key codes), though the difficulty level of using it may be beyond what you want.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616015/send-key-code-to-command-line-program-os-x-bash-script) SO question for a few more (less likely to work) options.

Comment: @typoking 1. Aren't there diffrerent codes for letters? DEC, HEX, and ASCII?
2. Ok so for example, F11 is /1. How do I mkake it press that key? Tutorial link one didn't work, and link two was WAY beyond me.

Comment: Got the first link working, ALSO over my head. I just want to be able to activate any given key. How would I do that?

Comment: @JShoe  Are you saying that certain keys do not work in your terminal?  What exactly do you mean that you want to "activate" any given key?

Comment: @typoking I want to be able to type some code into terminal and have it 'press' a key. So if I have text edit open and I run something in terminal it will type something into text edit. Or if I want it to press 'command r' to refresh a page, for press f10 to increase keyboard lighting. Is this possible?

Comment: @JShoe, haha, ok.  I thought you were trying to remap your keys.  See updated answer.  You probably will not like it.